# Creating monthly summaries of different categories of purchases

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets with eight columns of my bookkeeping sheet:

```
A - Is the Date
B - Type-How I paid ex Credit Card, Bank or Cash
C - Name
D - Reference Number
E - Description
F - Is category Ex: Utilities, Salary, Rent, Savings and Extras
G - Credit (If it was a credit)
H - Debit
```

I'd like to get on a different sheet a summary categorized down by month and category. Example I want to see the amount of my November utilities.

Which formula do I use?

Comment: A pivot table should work for you- Try data/pivot table

Answer (score 3):

No single solution looks ideal. Your data is well organised but might be better organised, for example:

- add a column for the month if you want analysis by month (say `=ArrayFormula(month(B2:B))`).
- combine your Debit and Credit columns (say make the values negative for credits).

Then a pivot table should suit very well indeed (unfortunately Google Sheets cannot yet aggregate days of the month into months, "group", within the pivot table).

Otherwise you might use a query to select for the relevant month and to add together (algebraically) the debits and credits. However a pivot table may be easier to adjust for one month to another and for different views of the same data.